# continuity and integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

I need to prove the next:

"Let f and g continuous functions in $[a,b]$ such that $f(a)=g(a)$ and $\int_{a}^{x}f(x)dx=\int_{a}^{x}g(x)dx$, $\forall \; x \in [a,b]$ so $f(x)=g(x)$

My attempt is this:

By the fundamental theorem of calculus define $h(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(x)dx$ which is the same as having $h(x)=\int_{a}^{x}g(x)dx$

Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous then $h$ is continuous and differentiable in $]a,b[$, so:

$h'(x)=f(x)$ and $h'(x)=g(x)$ therefore $f(x)=g(x)$

However, I am not using the hypothesis that $f(a)=g(a)$ if you could help me, I would appreciate it

Comment: You are right. It is not necessary to assume that $f(a)=g(a)$.

Comment: Thanks, because I had my doubts !!